# ¿ Como conseguir sacar los años, meses, días entre fechas?

Tags: javascript

Hola he creado este programa guiándome de uno visto en google, pero a la hora del resultado me da 0, 0, 0 , 0.
Por otro lado, no encuentro la manera de poner los años, meses, meses, días y horas transcurridos. Osea añadir los años a lo que ya tengo, pero dando el tiempo bien, no lo que me da ahora.
¿ Que hago mal y que debo añadir ? Pues con lo que tengo solo saldría días, horas y minutos. Como digo también quería poner los años.
Gracias.

```js
var msegMinuto = 1000 * 60;
var msegHora = msegMinuto * 60;
var msegDia = msegHora * 24;

var nacimiento = new Date(1965, 7, 20)
var  hoy = new Date()

nacimiento.setMonth()
nacimiento.setDate()
nacimiento.setHours()

var tiempo = hoy - new Date()

//calcular dias 
var dias = Math.floor(tiempo / msegDia)
tiempo = tiempo - (dias * msegDia)

//calcula horas
var horas = Math.floor(tiempo / msegHora)
tiempo = tiempo - (horas * msegHora)

var minutos = Math.floor(tiempo /msegMinuto)
tiempo = tiempo - (minutos * msegMinuto)

console.log("Han pasado " + dias + "dias, " + horas +" horas, y"+  minutos + "minutos desde que naciste.')
```

Comment: Bueno es que para empezar estas haciendo una concatenación incorrecta de valores, debería ser algo asi: console.log('Han pasado'+ dias + 'dias'+ horas + "horas y" + minutos + "minutis desde que naciste")

Comment: el otro detalle por el que te sale 0 es que a dodne debes pasar los parametros de año mes y dia es en el métod date de la variable hoy y lo estas haciendo en la variable nacimiento que nunca mas usas

Comment: Además estás haciendo var tiempo = hoy - new Date() cuando "hoy" es también "new Date()" por lo que estás restando la misma fecha (de ahí que te dé cero). Supongo que querías hacer var tiempo = nacimiento - hoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos te dejo la respuesta a tu cuestionamiento.

primero el mes, dia y año lo estabas asignando al método date de una variable llamada nacimiento pero ahí no es donde lo ocupas
segundo estabas concatenando mal los valores, te dejo en el código siguiente como hacerlo correctamente
tercero y ultimo el resultado de la var tiempo lo estabas restando al reves primero debería ser new Date() - hoy y tu lo tenías al reves lo que provocaba que saliera en las pruebas como negativo

```
var msegMinuto = 1000 * 60;
var msegHora = msegMinuto * 60;
var msegDia = msegHora * 24;

var nacimiento = new Date()
var  hoy = new Date(1989, 8, 12)

nacimiento.setMonth()
nacimiento.setDate()
nacimiento.setHours()

var tiempo = new Date() - hoy

//calcular dias 
var dias = Math.floor(tiempo / msegDia)
tiempo = tiempo - (dias * msegDia)

//calcula horas
var horas = Math.floor(tiempo / msegHora)
tiempo = tiempo - (horas * msegHora)

var minutos = Math.floor(tiempo /msegMinuto)
tiempo = tiempo - (minutos * msegMinuto)

console.log(dias)

console.log(`Han pasado ${dias} dias ${horas} horas y ${minutos} minutis desde que naciste`)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero lo añadir los años en primer lugar, seria muy complicado, Osea han pasado X años, X dias Y X horas...???

Comment: Aqui tienes en cuenta los años bisiestos?

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece ser que la diferencia de tiempo no la estas calculando entre el momento actual y el nacimiento, que supongo que es lo que quieres hacer. En lugar de hacer obtener un nuevo objeto Date() al hacer la resta, deberías restar los dos objetos que ya tenias.
Por cierto, no se que pretendías hacer usando los métodos setMonth, setDate y setHours pero lo que conseguiste es borrar los datos de la fecha (o más concretamente establecerlos a NaN) por no pasar ningún valor a funciones que requieren uno, seguro que este programa sobrevive sin esas líneas aunque quisiera que me contestaras cual era su finalidad.

```js
var msegMinuto = 1000 * 60;
var msegHora = msegMinuto * 60;
var msegDia = msegHora * 24;

var nacimiento = new Date(1965, 7, 20)
var  hoy = new Date()

var tiempo = hoy - nacimiento

//calcular días 
var dias = Math.floor(tiempo / msegDia)
tiempo = tiempo - (dias * msegDia)

//calcula horas
var horas = Math.floor(tiempo / msegHora)
tiempo = tiempo - (horas * msegHora)

var minutos = Math.floor(tiempo /msegMinuto)
tiempo = tiempo - (minutos * msegMinuto)

console.log("Han pasado " + dias + " días, " + horas +" horas, y"+  minutos + "minutos desde que naciste.")
```

Comment: Gracias @Saul Axel Martinez Ortiz , pues que lo vi en un ejemplo, pero como bien dices revisando viene `date.setMonth(0);
date.setDate(1);
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` Yo lo que queria era añadir también los años transcurridos, años, meses , días y horas